# Laravel - "Operator does not exist" exception when fetching a related model with an UUID key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm running into issues working with a Laravel 8 app. I have two models, `User` and `Post`. `Post` belongs to `User`.

Both models have UUID as primary keys, and are modeled as such (using PostgreSQL):

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        });

        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

The relationship is defined as this:

```
    // Post.php

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
    }
```

Both models also have `public $incrementing = false` to account for the UUIDs.

The `PostsController` fetches some Posts as well as their related Users:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::with('user')->paginate(10);
    }
```

However this is throwing the following exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = integer LINE 1: select * from "users" where "users"."id" in (3) ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "users" where "users"."id" in (3))
```

Laravel is treating the User's id as an integer (note the `3`, the only User on the DB has an id beginning with  `3a6bc3c3...`). However I cannot seem to find the root cause nor a fix for this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to also set the `protected $keyType` as on `Model` it is set as `int`:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

> "If your **primary key** is not an integer, you should set the protected `$keyType` property on your model to `string`"

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Model Conventions - Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: That was it... Shame on me for not combing through the docs more thoroughly. Thanks!